# How to compute efficiently the winner of a chess match where players are algorithms

Tags: algorithms

This is my problem:

1. The chess match starts with a board where chess pieces are randomly placed.
2. Both players are controlled by the same deterministic algorithm so if two games start with the same positions both games will end with the same result.

I need an algorithm capable of efficiently calculating which player will win the game (or if it is a draw). It is ok if the algorithm is able to calculate the result with a high accuracy (>99%).

Comment: I suspect the most efficient algorithm would be to literally simulate the game and see what happens...

Comment: If there was a known shortcut to predicting the winner, this could be used by chess programs to modify the strategy on time. But it is not the case.

Comment: @YvesDaoust but in this case you can predict who will win because both players are machines and you know what moves are they going to do (you know the algorithm).

Comment: @nirshahar and what about using a Neural Network?

Comment: How would you use a neural network (or any other machine learning technique) to accurately predict that? Seems very challenging, to say the least. Probably not the best task to give to machine-learning based algorithms

Comment: If such shortcuts were possible, they would already be in use, even in non symmetrical plays.